# How to use GeoServer SQL views in Openlayers 4

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, wmts

This is the my script that I am currently using to show my GeoServer layers in OpenLayers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMTS Layer from Capabilities</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      ol.proj.setProj4(proj4);
      proj4.defs('EPSG:27700','+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs');
      const proj27700 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700');
      const center_point = [394108.6719, 331807.5317];

      var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
      var map;

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ui/gwc/service/wmts?request=GetCapabilities').then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      }).then(function(text) {
        var result = parser.read(text);
        var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
          layer: 'intersects_new',
          matrixSet: 'EPSG:27700',
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
        });

        map = new ol.Map({
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              opacity: 1,
              source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                attributions: 'Tiles © <a href="https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                'rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer">ArcGIS</a> 2018',
              url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
                'World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
              crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
              })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              opacity: 1,
              source: new ol.source.WMTS((options))
            })
          ],
          target: 'map',
          view: new ol.View({
            projection: proj27700,
            center: center_point,
            zoom: 6
          })
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `intersect_new` layer is a SQL view, which is working and uses default parameters I set in GeoServer. I would like to use the `viewparams` to change the parameters as in the below link:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ui/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ui:intersects_new&styles=&bbox=-84702.61914736108,-9272.577651805477,676223.7241900009,1242876.667023777&width=466&height=768&srs=EPSG:27700&format=application/openlayers&viewparams=district:Barnet
```

I have gone through the OpenLayers documentation and I can't find viewparams as an option for either WMS or WMTS requests. Does anyone know how I can add this as an option to my fetch request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set `viewparams`, you just need to change `params` options in the WMS

```
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: 'https://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
  params: {'LAYERS': 'ui:intersects_new', 'TILED': true, VERSION: '1.1.1', viewparams: 'district:Barnet'},
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
  transition: 0
})
```

For WMTS, with your code, add

```
var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
  layer: 'intersects_new',
  matrixSet: 'EPSG:27700',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  viewparams: 'district:Barnet'
});
```

PS: I'm not sure WMTS support `viewparams` option

Comment: viewparams works for WMS, sadly it doesn't seem to work WMTS. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

For WMTS any additional parameters not supported by OpenLayers can be added using a custom tile url function:

```
var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
  layer: 'intersects_new',
  matrixSet: 'EPSG:27700',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

var source = new ol.source.WMTS(options);
var defaultTileUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction().bind(source);

source.setTileUrlFunction(function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
    return defaultTileUrlFunction(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) + '&viewparams=district:Barnet';
});
```

or better by using the `dimensions` option (as in https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wmts-dimensions.html)

```
var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
  layer: 'intersects_new',
  matrixSet: 'EPSG:27700',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  dimensions: {viewParams: 'district:Barnet'}
});
```